# WebSockets, Comet, AJAX & Long Polling

Tags: javascript, ajax, websocket, comet, long-polling

My understanding of **Comet** is that its a server-side AJAX request. My understanding of **Long Polling** ("Push") is that it is also a server-side AJAX request. My understanding of **WebSockets** is that they are a two-way AJAX request.

If any of these are wrong, please begin by correcting me!

Assuming I'm more or less correct, is it true that these are all just AJAX (JavaScript using `XmlHttpRequest` object under the hood)? If they are not all just AJAX calls, then how do you implement them in the client (via JavaScript) and on the server (using something like Java)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not necessarily.  You could use iframes.

Comment: `WebSocket` is a solid two-way connection between client and server, there is no requests (Apart from initial handshake) - you just send data and get data directly. This scales much better than having to make a new request for every message.

Comment: Regarding the terminology part of your question, you can check-out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782058/periodic-pull-comet-long-polling-websockets/10785129#10785129

As for the two-way aspects of Comet and WebSockets, check out the final part of this article: http://cometdaily.com/2011/07/06/push-technology-comet-and-websockets-10-years-of-history-from-lightstreamers-perspective/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of `WebSockets` is incorrect. WebSockets is a new protocol and provides a new API that has nothing to do with `XmlHttpRequest`.

This is how you create a WebSocket

```
var exampleSocket = new WebSocket(
    "ws://www.example.com/socketserver", "protocolOne"
);
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebSockets/

Comment: Thanks @Otto (+1) - am I correct about Comet and Long Polling being AJAX-based?

Comment: @AdamTannon Read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)#Implementations)

Comment: How would this WebSocket be handled on the server-side? Would it just be a server listening at that URL/port? In Java I assume this would come across the wire as an `HttpServletRequest`, and could be serviced by replying with an `HttpServletResponse`?

Comment: @Adam Have a look at Jetty's implementation: http://blogs.webtide.com/gregw/entry/jetty_websocket_server